# Incrementing a pointer in Go

Tags: pointers, go

Could anyone tell me how to increment a pointer through a string in Go?

I've tried `ptr += 1` like in C but it says that the types *string and int are incompatible. Thanks

Comment: Maybe just cast it into an integer, increment, then cast it back

Answer (score 5):

Go [FAQ: Why is there no pointer arithmetic?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#no_pointer_arithmetic)

> Safety. Without pointer arithmetic it's possible to create a language that can never derive an illegal address that succeeds incorrectly. Compiler and hardware technology have advanced to the point where a loop using array indices can be as efficient as a loop using pointer arithmetic. Also, the lack of pointer arithmetic can simplify the implementation of the garbage collector.

So the answer is no, you can't increment a pointer in Go.