# Get *uint8 pointer to a first character in a string

Tags: string, pointers, go

I am trying to port a hash function from C to Go using `unsafe.Pointer`. I need to get the pointer to the first character of the key string.

I tried `&(hello[0])` and `&hello[0]` and failed.

Comment: You most likely have an xy problem. If you need to iterate through the bytes in a string, there are nice go-ways to do it than without using a pointer.

Comment: @nos unfortunately not, there is a heavy pointer arithmetic that deals with the caracters in a string as bytes, words and dwords.

Comment: You cannot deal with "characters" in a string as bytes, at least not in the Unicode world.

Comment: @exebook Then that is of vital importance to your question, and you should mention explicitly what you need to do. There are ways to do what you need, but your question is too open ended. It's better that you give concrete problems or code snippets, so you can get concrete answers . You still might need to re-write the code and not do a 1:1 porting from C though.

Comment: @nos thank you, created a specific question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507846/porting-meiyan-hash-function-to-go

Answer (score 2):

`string` values in Go are immutable, and therefore not [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators); so you cannot take the address of its runes or bytes. If you could, you could modify the pointed value and thus modify the content of the `string` value. In Go there is also [no pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046389/incrementing-a-pointer-in-go/41046421#41046421).

What you can do is simply [index](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) the `string`, indexing a `string` indexes its bytes (in UTF-8 encoded form, this is how Go stores `string` values in memory). You can "mimic" the pointer arithmetic with "index arithmetic".

See this example:

```
s := "Hello World"
i := 0
fmt.Println(s[i], string(s[i]))
i += 4
fmt.Println(s[i], string(s[i]))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oDLxVhGFks)):

```
72 H
111 o
```

You may also convert the `string` to a `[]byte` or `[]rune`, should you have the need to do so (e.g. if you need to modify the bytes), and you can work with that. Slices are also addressable. Note that converting a `string` value to the mentioned slice types will make a copy of the `string` content (to preserve the immutability of the `string`).

While it's the `rune` type that represents a Unicode character, if you're trying to reproduce a hash algorithm, you most likely want to work with bytes, so convert it to a byte slice (which is the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the `string`):

```
s := "Hello World"
b := []byte(s)
// Here you can work with b which is addressable
```

Note that in Go, the types `byte` and `uint8` are "identical", `byte` is an alias for `uint8`, you can also write:

```
s := "Hello World"
b := []uint8(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

In golang string it's a massive of bytes, need convert string to rune

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func test(r *rune) {
    *r = rune('L')
}

func main() {
    s := []rune("Hello")
    fmt.Println(string(s))
    fmt.Println(&s[0])
    test(&s[0])
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```

[Example playground golang](https://play.golang.org/p/zCLqEvBVZE)