# Porting MeiYan hash function to Go

Tags: performance, go, hash

I wanted to port a state-of-the-art hash function MeiYan from C to Go. (As far as I know this is one of the best if not just the best hash function for hash tables in terms of speed and collision rate, it beats MurMur at least.)

I am new to Go, just spent one weekend with it, and came up with this version:

```
func meiyan(key *byte, count int) uint32 {
    type P *uint32;
    var h uint32 = 0x811c9dc5;
    for ;count >= 8; {
        a := ((*(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(key))) << 5)
        b := ((*(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(key))) >> 27)
        c := *(*uint32)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(key)) + 4))
        h = (h ^ ((a | b) ^ c)) * 0xad3e7
        count -= 8
        key = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(key)) + 8))
    }
    if (count & 4) != 0 {
        h = (h ^ uint32(*(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(key)) + 2))
        h = (h ^ uint32(*(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(key)) + 2))
    }
    if (count & 2) != 0 {
        h = (h ^ uint32(*(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(key)) + 2))
    }
    if (count & 1) != 0 {
        h = (h ^ uint32(*key));
        h = h * 0xad3e7
    }
    return h ^ (h >> 16);
}
```

Looks messy, but I do not think I can make it look better. Now I measure the speed and it is frustratingly slow, 3 times slower than C/C++ when compiled with `gccgo -O3`. Can this be made faster? Is this just as good as compiler can make it or `unsafe.Pointer` conversion is just as slow as it gets? In fact this surprised me, because I have seen that some other number crunching style code was just as fast as C or even faster. Am I doing something inneficiently here?

Here is the original C code I am porting from:

```
u32 meiyan(const char *key, int count) {
    typedef u32* P;
    u32 h = 0x811c9dc5;
    while (count >= 8) {
        h = (h ^ ((((*(P)key) << 5) | ((*(P)key) >> 27)) ^ *(P)(key + 4))) * 0xad3e7;
        count -= 8;
        key += 8;
    }
    #define tmp h = (h ^ *(u16*)key) * 0xad3e7; key += 2;
    if (count & 4) { tmp tmp }
    if (count & 2) { tmp }
    if (count & 1) { h = (h ^ *key) * 0xad3e7; }
    #undef tmp
    return h ^ (h >> 16);
}
```

Here is how I measure speed:

```
func main(){
    T := time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6
    buf := []byte("Hello World!")
    var controlSum uint64 = 0
    for x := 123; x < 1e8; x++ {
        controlSum += uint64(meiyan(&buf[0], 12))
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6 - T, "ms")
    fmt.Println("controlSum:", controlSum)
}
```

Comment: Why not use Go benchmarks? https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur simple because I was learning go for 1.5 days so far.

Comment: Why are you using unsafe everywhere?

Comment: I would also advice using Go distribution 1.8 over gccgo. gccgo is behind.

Comment: All this unsafe.Pointer stuff is totally unnecessary. Write a function which takes 4 bytes and builds a uint32 from it and you'r done.

Comment: It seem to be a good question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur I used go 1.6.2, it is 3 times slower than gccgo (`go boud meiyan.go`), have they really improved that much in 1.8?

Comment: The C const char* key and int count translates to slice of bytes in Go []byte.

Answer (score 3):

After some careful research I found out why my code was slow, and improved it so it is now faster than the C version in my tests:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

func meiyan(key *byte, count int) uint32 {
    type un unsafe.Pointer
    type p32 *uint32
    type p16 *uint16
    type p8 *byte
    var h uint32 = 0x811c9dc5;
    for ;count >= 8; {
        a := *p32(un(key)) << 5
        b := *p32(un(key)) >> 27
        c := *p32(un(uintptr(un(key)) + 4))
        h = (h ^ ((a | b) ^ c)) * 0xad3e7
        count -= 8
        key = p8(un(uintptr(un(key)) + 8))
    }
    if (count & 4) != 0 {
        h = (h ^ uint32(*p16(un(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = p8(un(uintptr(un(key)) + 2))
        h = (h ^ uint32(*p16(un(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = p8(un(uintptr(un(key)) + 2))
    }
    if (count & 2) != 0 {
        h = (h ^ uint32(*p16(un(key)))) * 0xad3e7
        key = p8(un(uintptr(un(key)) + 2))
    }
    if (count & 1) != 0 {
        h = h ^ uint32(*key)
        h = h * 0xad3e7
    }
    return h ^ (h >> 16);
}

func main() {
    T := time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6
    buf := []byte("ABCDEFGHABCDEFGH")
    var controlSum uint64 = 0
    start := &buf[0]
    size := len(buf)
    for x := 123; x < 1e8; x++ {
        controlSum += uint64(meiyan(start, size))
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6 - T, "ms")
    fmt.Println("controlSum:", controlSum)
}
```

The hash function itself was already fast, but dereferencing the array on each iteration is what made it slow: `&buf[0]` was replaced with `start := &buf[0]` and then use `start` on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation from [NATS](https://github.com/nats-io/sublist/blob/master/hash/hash.go) looks impressive! On my machine, for a data of length 30 (bytes) **op/sec 157175656.56** and **nano-sec/op 6.36**! Take a look at it. You might find some ideas.

Comment: The problem with this implementation is the copyright. It states "Copyright 2012 Apcera Inc. All rights reserved."

Comment: I've presented it as some source for ideas and the license for the package is MIT - on the bottom of the front page - and as far as I'm aware it's one of the most liberal OSS licenses (https://github.com/nats-io/sublist) and you can even use it in a commercial product.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian yesterday I benchmarked NATS version, it was slower than my straightforward port from C, I forgot the numbers already, I think it was 3 times slower or so. It uses slices heavily where it should use pointers, and each index dereference is a performance killer.

Comment: Awesome! :) Looking forward to final version!